# reply all to my bcc recipients

Tags: outlook, ms-office

Is there a way to reply all to my bcc list?

I sent an email from outlook and added bunch of people to bcc. I want to reply all my original email but for some reason I don’t see any bcc recipients

Answer (score 0):

Of course - "B" in "BCC" stands for "blind". BCC recipients are not visible when the message is delivered.

Comment: as a sender, I should be able to see bcc list. I composed email, added bunch of people to bcc and sent an email. I now want to reply all for follow up email. thanks

Comment: You can only see the BCC recipients in the Sent Items folder. Are you replying to a message in your Inbox?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to reply all from my inbox. I see BCC list in sent Items folder but reply all didn't work. I manually had to copy bcc emails to my followup email.